# chaco circle overlay tool

Tags: python, chaco

I would like to create a circle overlay tool with Chaco that is a much simpler version of the BetterSelectingZoom: left-down sets the circle center, drag while left-down draws the circle, left-up discards the circle. Unfortunately, I cannot quite follow the code in better_selecting_zoom.py; in particular, I don't quite understand how to add, delete, or modify the overlay circle on the fly. An attempt for CircleTool class is below.  Can anyone nudge me in the right direction?

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from traits.api import HasTraits, Instance
from traits.api import Bool, Tuple, Float
from traitsui.api import View, Item
from enable.api import Component, ComponentEditor
from chaco.api import Plot, ArrayPlotData
from chaco.api import AbstractOverlay, BaseTool

class CircleTool(AbstractOverlay,BaseTool):
    '''
    provides dynamic circle overlay on a plot: left down sets circle center,
    left down drag draws circle, left up removes circle overlay.
    '''

    _select_on = Bool(False) 
    _select_center = Tuple((0,0))
    _select_radius = Float(0)

    def __init__(self,component=None,**kwargs):
        '''
        initialize CircleTool as an overlay and a tool
        '''
        AbstractOverlay.__init__(self,component=component,**kwargs)
        BaseTool.__init__(self,component=component,**kwargs)

    def normal_left_down(self,event):
        '''
        set selection flag to True; save circle center; CircleTool to the
        overlays list of component (plot); discard event.
        '''
        self._select_on = True
        self._select_center = (event.x,event.y)
        self.component.overlays.append(self)        
        event.handled = True

    def normal_left_up(self,event):
        '''
        set selection flag to False; get index of the CircleTool overlay in 
        component's overlays list; discard CircleTool overlay; redraw plot;
        discard event.
        '''
        self._select_on = False
        ixself = self.component.overlays.index(self)
        self.component.overlays.pop(ixself)
        self.component.request_redraw()
        event.handled = True        

    def normal_mouse_move(self,event):
        '''
        if selection flag is True, get circle centre and current point;
        compute radius (coordinates and radius units are screen pixels.)
        demand redraw of plot which calls self.overlay()
        '''
        if not self._select_on: return
        xc, yc = self._select_center
        xp, yp = (event.x,event.y)
        self._select_radius = float(np.sqrt((xc-xp)**2 + (yc-yp)**2))
        self.component.request_redraw()

    def overlay(self,component,gc,view_bounds=None,mode='normal'):
        '''
        draw gc (Kiva Graphics Context System object) on component; define
        gc as a circle.  
        ??? in Chaco code, with gc is used.  Why?
        '''
        gc.set_line_width(2)
        gc.set_stroke_color((0,0,0))
        gc.clip_to_rect(component.x, component.y, component.width, component.height)
        gc.arc(self._select_center[0],self._select_center[1],self._select_radius,0,2*np.pi)
        gc.stroke_path()

class CircleOverlay(AbstractOverlay):
    '''
    basic test overlay: red circle at (200,300) with radius 50.
    '''
    def overlay(self,component,gc,view_bounds=False,mode='normal'):
        gc.set_stroke_color((1,0,0))
        gc.set_line_width(2)
        gc.arc(200,300,50,0,2*np.pi)
        gc.stroke_path()


class PlotExample(HasTraits):
    plot = Instance(Component)
    traits_view = View(Item('plot',editor=ComponentEditor()),
                       width=500,height=500,resizable=True,
                       title='TEST-CIRCLE-TOOL')

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(PlotExample,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        # create plot
        x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
        y = np.sin(x)
        plotData = ArrayPlotData(x=x,y=y)
        plot = Plot(plotData)
        plot.plot(('x','y'),type='line')

        # append circle tool
        circleTool = CircleTool(component=plot)
        plot.tools.append(circleTool)

        # append circle overlay
        circleOverlay = CircleOverlay(component=plot)
        plot.overlays.append(circleOverlay)

        # save plot for later
        self.plot = plot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plotExample = PlotExample()
    plotExample.configure_traits()
```

Comment: after some messing around, I managed to solve the problem myself.  A minimal example for a circle overlay tool in Chaco is above.